# Compare value in a column to an integer

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm pretty new to pandas and python. I want to compare the value in a column to an integer to see if they are equal and then generate a new columd. I tried eq() and equals(), both of them gives me an error

> ValueError:
>   The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Below is the code that I used.

```
data_frame["FirstName"] = data_frame["SplitName"].str[0] if data_frame["Length"].eq(2) else ""
```

SplitName column is a list and Length column is all integer.

Comment: Are you sure the data type of `data_frame["Length"]` is `int`?

Comment: what is `data_frame["SplitName"].str[0]`?

Comment: SplitName is a list and I want to get the first element

Answer (score 1):

Just use `np.where`

```
import numpy as np
data_frame["FirstName"] = np.where(data_frame["Length"].eq(2), "string_if_equal_2", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can just do `where`

```
data_frame["FirstName"] = data_frame["SplitName"].str[0].where(data_frame["Length"].eq(2),'')
```

Comment: @LarryDing yw : -) happy coding ~